# Filter Tree using XSLT

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath

i have xml file in tree structure like this final.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="b.xsl"?> 
<childrens>
<child_1 entity_id="1" value="Root Catalog" parent_id="0">
    <child_2 entity_id="2" value="Navigate" parent_id="1">
        <child_4 entity_id="4" value="Activities" parent_id="2">
            <child_10066 entity_id="10066" value="Physical1" parent_id="4">
                <child_10067 entity_id="10067" value="Cricket" parent_id="10066">
                    <child_10068 entity_id="10068" value="One Day" parent_id="10067"/>
                </child_10067>
            </child_10066>
            <child_10069 entity_id="10069" value="Test2" parent_id="4"/>
            <child_10070 entity_id="10070" value="Test3" parent_id="4"/>
            <child_10071 entity_id="10071" value="Test4" parent_id="4"/>
            <child_10072 entity_id="10072" value="Test5" parent_id="4"/>
            <child_5 entity_id="5" value="Physical" parent_id="4"/>
        </child_4>
        <child_4331 entity_id="4331" value="Region" parent_id="2">
            .
            .
            .
            .
        </child_4331>
    </child_2>
</child_1>
</childrens>
```

here is my xslt code

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output method="html" indent="yes" omit-xml-declaration="yes"/>

  <xsl:template match="*" mode="item">
        <li>
          <xsl:value-of select="@value"/>
          <xsl:apply-templates select="current()[*]"/>
        </li>
 </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="*/*/*">
    <ul>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="*[1] | node()[current()/ancestor::*[3]]" mode="item"/>
     <xsl:if test="local-name(child::*) = 'child_4'"><div id="Activity"></div></xsl:if>
    </ul>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

and i have another xml file which contains the id of the leaf node
i want to display only those node which is in `filter.xml` file (with its parent id)

and the filter.xml is

```
<products>
  <product_id value="1">
    <tab_id value="351">
      <tab_name value="test1"/>
      <dist_activity value="5"/>
      <dist_activity value="10068"/>
      <dist_activity value="10070"/>
    </tab_id>
  </product_id>
  <product_id value="2">
    <tab_id value="352">
      <tab_name value="test2"/>
      <dist_activity value="10069"/>
    </tab_id>
  </product_id>
</products>
```

here dist_activity contains the id of the leaf node which is entity_id in the main xml file so i want output using this 2 xml file. currently i am using only main xml file not the `filter.xml`  file here is my current output and the out put which i want using both file

[image]

here is in filter.xml for One day(10068),Test2(10069),test3(10070),Physical(5) so i want only those in my tree

so what changes do i need to do in my `xslt` code ???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not completely clear (for me) how the filter should work. From your statement:
 *here is in filter.xml for One day(10068),Test2(10069),test3(10070),Physical(5) so i want only those in my tree*
and the filter.xml I expect:
You like to have `li` elements in your output for child_xxxx elements where  entity_id   of self or an descendant exist as @value of dist_activity in filter.xml.

Therefore try this small change to your xlst:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="html" indent="yes" omit-xml-declaration="yes"/>

    <xsl:variable name="filter" select="document('iz1_filter.xml')"/>

    <xsl:template match="*" mode="item">
        <xsl:if test="$filter//dist_activity[@value= current()/descendant-or-self::*/@entity_id ]" >
            <li>
                <xsl:value-of select="@value"/>
                <xsl:apply-templates select="current()[*]"/>
            </li>
        </xsl:if>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="*/*/*">
        <ul>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="*[1] | node()[current()/ancestor::*[3]]" mode="item"/>
            <xsl:if test="local-name(child::*) = 'child_4'">
                <div id="Activity"></div>
            </xsl:if>
        </ul>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Which will generate the following output:

```
<ul>
    <li>
        Activities<ul>
            <li>
                Physical1<ul>
                    <li>
                        Cricket<ul>
                            <li>One Day</li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li>Test2</li>
            <li>Test3</li>
            <li>Physical</li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <div id="Activity"></div>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

`node()[current()/ancestor::*[3]]` selects all child nodes with at least three ancestors. Since the current node has two parents, all its children all have three ancestors, guaranteed.

If you want to select ones with only three previous siblings, try the `preceding-sibling` axis, not the `ancestor` axis.

Comment: i want output usnig `filter.xml`

Comment: Is that what you actually want? If you just want the first three items, why not `select="node()[position() < 4]"`?